# Why is my command line argument handling crashing my program?

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments, argv

Why is something so seemingly simple is crashing my program?

I am trying to get a value for `n` to make an array the size of `N` and perform various operations on it, but that's beside the point. Anyways, It keeps crashing every time I try to access `argv[1]`.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  int n;
  n = atoi(argv[1]); //Crashes here!
  cout << "\nN: " << n << endl;
}
```

Comment: You must not have given an argument.

Comment: What arguments are you giving, and what sort of crash do you get?

Comment: By the way, if you're planning on `Type arr[n];`, that's not standard C++. The proper solution is `std::vector` or likewise, in which case I wouldn't really term it an array.

Comment: I get the array that Debug assertion failed!and that nptr != NULL

Answer (score 1):

Does argv[1] exist? To prevent your code from accessing memory it should not check how many arguments were passed.

```
if(argc >= 2)
  n = argv[1];
else
  std::cout << "Proper usage: .....\n";
```

This seems like a great time to learn how to use your debugger to view the contents of argv and argc.

Comment: How do I "Give" an argument? I thought that the arc and argv[] WERE the arguments?

Comment: argv contains the arguments you pass to the program when executing it. If you are running your program from the command line you would type the following "myprogram firstargument secondargument". Have you ever used the command cd from the command prompt? If so you probably typed cd directoryname to move to the directoryname directory. In that case directoryname is an argument that the cd program could access.

Comment: Okay I understand that. How do I Give it an argument?

Comment: Depends on your operating system or your IDE. Try searching for the name of your IDE and how to pass command line arguments.